# Changing the VSTS approver policy from a particular branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-branch, pull-request

I'm using git and VSTS and I have a several Pull Requests into the develop branch that I've approved and I'd like to Complete.  The changes in these branches are really trivial, just translation strings.

In branch policies I can change the Code Review requirements for feature/TranslationString123, but that doesn't really help me, since I'm trying to merge the contents of those branches into the develop branch.

I believe that I have the permissions to change the Minimum number of reviewers to 1 for the develop branch, but that doesn't seem like a good idea.  Does anyone have a good idea for a way to expedite the approve the completion of these specific branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an "Exempt from policy enforcement" option under the branch "Security" settings. Set it to "Allow" will allow you to complete the pull request bypass the branch policies.
[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I'd been using the Rewrite and destroy history (force push) to allow me to delete branches after completing pull requests.  I hadn't notice the Exempt from policy enforcement one.  I set it for the feature/Translation123 branch and tried to complete it, but got the "The pull request needs a minimum number of approvals (2) from other users before it can be completed" error again.

Comment: It looks like I can temporarily make Project Administrators "Exempt for policy enforcement" on the development branch.  It would be safer if I could change a setting on the feature branch that I'm doing the pull request from.

Comment: @Eric I'm afraid there isn't any option to configure this for now. The changes of pull request is finally applied to the development branch, that's why you need to configure the settings for development branch, rather than feature branch.